# Node Lighthouse not returning similar results for accessibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, lighthouse

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or missing a config setting but when I run LH in the Chrome extension, my page receives a 94 but when I run the same page in the node LH I am getting an 88. I figured out the running it as a desktop vs mobile but I am not sure what else I am missing to get the scores the same or more similar.

My current code

```
const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: ['--headless']});
    const options = {logLevel: 'info', output: 'html', onlyCategories: ['accessibility'], port: chrome.port};
    // emulatedFormFactor:'desktop'
    const config = { extends: 'lighthouse:default', settings: {formFactor: 'desktop', screenEmulation:{mobile:false}} }
    const runnerResult = await lighthouse(, options, config);
```

I expected a slight difference between the two but I think 6pts is a little dramatic. I noticed that the throttle rate is different between the two but not sure how to change that is the settings or config.

[image: Image on the right is the Chrome Browser and left is the node saved page]

Image on the right is the Chrome Browser and left is the node saved page

Comment: Have you expanded the "buttons do not have an accessible name" error in Chrome browser? That is where the difference in score is coming from but without knowing what element it is pointing to there isn't much we can do to offer any help.

Comment: Actually I have an educated guess - your menu button on mobile I would imagine is just a hamburger icon, am I right?

Comment: Good catch! The hamburger menu only shows in mobile and this is supposed to test for desktop. Am I missing something in my config that it wouldn't be testing for desktop despite it saying it is?

Comment: It is hard to tell why it is running the mobile version, the only thing I can think of is you have the screen too small (too narrow) or have mobile emulation turned on in the main browser settings (top left of dev tools) as it will still honour normal responsive settings on the desktop version. When you run it which break point of the site do you see? The weird thing is that you also have throttling that is the same as mobile applied (CPU slowdown and network throttling - did you set these in the performance tab?).

Comment: As you can see in the code, I am running a headless node version so there is no browser or performance tab. I was looking to see if anyone could look at my setting and let me know if I am missing something to have this emulate a desktop and manage the throttling in code.

Answer (score 3):

After doing a ton of googling I finally found the answer to get my Node Lighthouse to use the same parameters as the Chrome extension version.

Here is the final code:

```
const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: ['--headless']});
    const flags = {logLevel: 'info', output: 'html', onlyCategories: ['accessibility'], port: chrome.port};
    const config = {
        extends: 'lighthouse:default',
        settings: {
          formFactor: 'desktop',
          throttling: {
            rttMs: 40,
            throughputKbps: 10240,
            cpuSlowdownMultiplier: 1,
            requestLatencyMs: 0,
            downloadThroughputKbps: 0,
            uploadThroughputKbps: 0
          },
          screenEmulation: {
            mobile: false,
            width: 1350,
            height: 940,
            deviceScaleFactor: 1,
            disabled: false
          },
          emulatedUserAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse'
        }
      }
    const runnerResult = await lighthouse('https://yourawesomesite.com', flags, config);
```

Hope this helps someone else automate their Lighthouse testing.